# How to Find a Token Substring?

Tags: java

I am currently working on a code that requires me to use the String Tokenizer method in order to evaluate expressions.  This is fine as I understand how to use them, but in order to add the new value to the string and delete the two calculated values (because the method must be recursive), I wanted to use the `String.replace()` method.  However, I cannot figure out how to find the substring of the two tokens, I tried it this way:

```
for(int j=0; j<expr.length(); j++)
{
    int firstSub = 0;
    int secondSub = 0;
    int sign = j;
    if(expr.charAt(j)=='*')
    {
        while(j != '/' || j!='+' || j!='-')
        {
            j--;
        }
        firstSub = j+1;
        while(sign != '/' || j!='+' || j!='-')
        {
            sign++;
        }
        secondSub = sign-1;
    }
}
```

which unfortunately did not work.  Is there anyway to find the substring of two tokens?

Comment: `while(j != '/' || j!='+' || j!='-')` - You're comparing an int to a char.

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is exactly but wouldn't `input.replace( tokens[0], "whatever").replace( tokens[1], "whatever")`  do the trick?

Comment: Can you please specify an example of what you would like to achieve using String tokenizer?

Comment: @SteveSmith you _can_ compare `int` and `char`. Try `65 == 'A'`.

Comment: Without knowing anything about the problem, I feel confident to state "your problem most likely would be better solved by not using recursion".  Recursion is for the weak.

Comment: @Thomas True.  I should have clarified he's comparing the position (as an int) with a char, which makes not a lot of sense.  I think he wants charAt().

Comment: @SteveSmith yes, that's right. It should be something like `expr.charAt(j) != '/'` etc. best with storing the character in its own variable first. But besides that I'm not sure this needs to be that complicated. Most probably a combination of `replace()`, `indexOf()`, `substring()` etc. is sufficient.

Comment: @SteveSmith, yea that was kind of silly of me to do did not even think that I did that, I changed it and it works now, except that the firstSub and secondSub value are remaining at 0.

Answer (score 2):

There are (at least) 2 bugs:

#### Bug 1) Use `charAt()`:

```
while(exp.charAt(j) != '/' && exp.charAt(j)!='+' && exp.charAt(j)!='-')
```

#### Bug 2) Use `&&`

Note both `charAt()` *and* change in logic from `||` to `&&`; with `||` the condition is always true.

You'll need to apply the same change to the next `if`.

Comment: hard to understand what he is trying to do without correcting the bugs

Comment: @toongeorges he's trying to find the nearest operator to the left and right of the `*`